# Ideas for parsing string with variable whitespace

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way to parse strings that contain about 3-4 columns of data with variable whitespace between each element. I'd like to split each line into its respective components. Examples are below:

```
WHITE BLOOD CELL COUNT      10.2        4.0-10.8
HEMOGLOBIN   8.9   ABNORMAL LOW    12-16
PLATELET COUNT     250    160-400
```

So in the above examples, two lines have three elements, one line has four elements. I want to find a way separate it. If the first element were one word it would be easy, but I don't see a simple way to do this other than going through each character and matching for either letter or number/period/dash and doing it that way.

Comment: sorry but what do you want to do? I cant understand.

Comment: Is the data in the same format each time, or does it change?

Comment: You need to define your grammar more clearly before you begin parsing input.

Comment: The data is in this same general format each time. It'll be in that specific order. The first element name will change based on the type of lab test, but it should be presented in this format. I want to be able to put each line into an array, like array[0] = "WHITE BLOOD CELL COUNT", array[1] = 10.2, array[2] = 4.0-10.8, etc.

Comment: `array_line1 = explode("  ", $inputstring)`. am i right when i guess, that the elements of each column are separated by a double or triple whitespace?

Comment: The whitespace between the columns is variable, but always at least more than one space.

Comment: @eluong Is something like [this](http://codepad.org/BdCHu8PO) what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data can be separated into rows using:

```
$rows = explode("\n", $str);
```

Then, for each row, you can split the data by columns using:

```
foreach($rows as $i => $row){
    $rows[$i] = preg_split ( '/\s{2,}/' , $row);
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://codepad.org/BdCHu8PO

Comment: why not explode the rows too?

Comment: @Vogel612 Because you can't use a regex in `explode`. If I were to simply use two spaces, there would be empty elements, and the separated columns could contain excess whitespace at the edges.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try later tonight, but it looks like this is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("#(.*?)(?:\s{2,}|\z)#",$str,$matches);
```

array will be stored in $matches[0]:

i.e.:

$matches[0][0] is WHITE BLOOD CELL COUNT

$matches[0][1] is 10.2

... etc

An example is here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e36760e284e1fdc5160755d866b5aaea4df3b16

The other answer works well already, but I thought I would include the one-step regex. :)